# How to create a searchbar for API data using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react, i have created a `User component` and `search bar` but unable to search the data from the component. I mean i couldn't able to figure it out how to searchBar component to work. How to filter the items as we type in the search bar.

Here is the component for User:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Container,
  Checkbox,
  Grid,
  Header,
  Button,
  Popup,
  Avatar,
  Icon,
  Divider
} from "semantic-ui-react";
import Search from "./Search";
export default class DataView extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      Users: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.fetchData();
  }
  fetchData() {
    fetch("api/Users")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          Users: data.item1
        });
      });
  }

  searchUsers = text => {
    console.log(text);
    fetch("api/Users")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          Users: data.item1
        });
      });
  };

  render() {
    const { Users } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Search searchUsers={this.searchUsers} />
        <Container>
          {Users.map(View => {
            return (
              <Grid key={View.id}>
                <Grid.Row>
                  <Checkbox />
                  <Header>
                    {View.firstName} {View.lastName}
                  </Header>
                </Grid.Row>
                <Divider />
                <Grid.Row>
                  <Avatar
                    name={View.firstName + " " + View.lastName}
                    maxInitials={2}
                    round={true}
                  />

                  <Grid.Column>
                    <Icon name="calendar outline" />
                    {View.experience}
                    <br />
                    <Icon name="money bill alternate outline" />
                    {View.salary}
                  </Grid.Column>
                </Grid.Row>
                <Divider />
                <Grid.Row>
                  <Grid.Column>
                    <Popup
                      content={View.email}
                      trigger={<Button icon="mail outline" />}
                    />

                  </Grid.Column>
                </Grid.Row>
              </Grid>
            );
          })}
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Search Component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Form, Input, Button } from "semantic-ui-react";
export default class Search extends Component {
  state = {
    text: ""
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      text: e.target.value
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.searchUsers(this.state.text);
    this.setState({ text: "" });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <Input
            type="text"
            name="text"
            placeholder="Search Here"
            value={this.state.text}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <Button type="submit" value="Search">
            Search
          </Button>
        </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

JSON data (API) would be like:

```
{
  "item1": [
    {
      "id": "2c963f",
      "firstName": "ABC",
      "lastName": "FED",
      "experience": 0,
        "salary": "20000",
         "email": "abc@gmail.com",
},

{
      "id": "2c963g",
      "firstName": "DEC",
      "lastName": "POI",
      "experience": 0,
        "salary": "15000",
         "email": "dec@gmail.com",
}

]

}
```

Can any one help me in fixing the search bar for the User component?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use material-ui. It has an autocomplete that works perfectly.

Here is a link to it: https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/

Here is a demo to try out: https://codesandbox.io/s/56m1p

If for some reason you cannot use material-ui, here is a link to a tutorial that could guide you to achieve what you need: https://programmingwithmosh.com/react/simple-react-autocomplete-component/

I hope this helps and makes it easy for you

Comment: If i use material UI then i have to change every compoent into material UI, design may collapse if i use both semantic and material ui

Comment: I have updated my answer. please check the new link added

Comment: Adn you don't have to change every component. You can decide to use material-ui for just the specific autocomplete area.

Comment: It's coming. I've used previously but some conflicts are coming.